# Display content based on checkbox - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 8 divs.initially 4 of them are displayed and remaining 4 are styled as dislay:none.

The [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pssmjsvy/1/) code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pssmjsvy/1/)

First 4 checkbox correspond to the first 4 divs. When 1st checkbox is unchecked the first div is disabled and default div `empty` is enabled. similarly when 2nd checkbox is unchecked the 2nd div is diabled and default div `empty` is enabled. similarly 3rd and 4th divs.

The last 4 checkbox correspond to last 4 divs. These checkbox must be enabled to check or uncheck only if any of the first 4 divs are disabled and when any of these 4 checkbox are enabled the corresponding div must be displayed in the place of default div.

for example checkbox with `name=box1` is unchecked then `div_box_1` must be disabled and div `empty` must be enabled. After this if checkbox with `name=box6` is checked then div `empty` must be disabled and `div_box_6` must be enabled.

Comment: "*The FIDDLE code is here*" - unfortunately, your code needs to be *here*, in your question. Though the Fiddle is a nice bonus, and does make it easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

The way jQuery selectors work, is for every peice of text you add, it'll think its another child node or w/e.

The problem is :
`$("input.css-checkbox:checkbox").click(function(){`

Your selecting the  with the class "css-checkbox" already. With the :checkbox it assumes something MORE after that. ( I forget what this selector does TBH ) But when you remove the ":checkbox" it hides and shows.

`$("input.css-checkbox").click(function(){`